# How can I call eventhandler?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

```
void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
int take = currentPage * 10;
int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 10;
FetchData(take, skip);
}
```

Hi,

I want to call the method lbl_Click() whenever the click happens.

How can I define any aspx tag to call a function " lbl_Click()" whenever the click happens? or can I use javascript to invoke this  "lbl_Click()" function?

Comment: When I am calling CreatePagingControl() method it does not go inside the lbl_click() method so how am I able to go into that function because everytime I need to call FetchData() with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Code for Event handler **lbl_Click** would be executed only when  **Click Event** is fired from the link button. Functionally, this should happen when you click your paging link buttons.

Try to put a breakpoint in lbl_Click function and fire event by clicking on the paging link buttons in UI.

Since, it is still not working for you. I have created a small working page to show you how it should be.

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicLinkControls();
    }

    private void CreateDynamicLinkControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lk = new LinkButton();
            lk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
            lk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
            lk.Text = (i + 1).ToString() + "&nbsp;";
            this.form1.Controls.Add(lk);
        }
    }

    void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text.Substring(0, 1));
        lblLinkText.Text = currentPage.ToString();
    }
}
```

ASPX Page

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        You Clicked : <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLinkText"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Using this Code**

Try to run the page and then link button would appear on the page, label is placed on the page which displays which page was clicked.

Comment: Yea I have done that when I click linkbutton it doesnt go inside it only keep repeating the createpagingcount() method.

Comment: Could you add the complete page code behind code ? It might be that function CreatePagingControl is called from another place

Comment: is there any code in page_load, page_init methods also ?

Comment: From the posted code, i can see, that in Page_LoadComplete again you are calling the CreatePagingControl() method. When you click on a button then postback would be initiated to server and after button click event, Page_LoadComplete event would also be fired.

Comment: If i remove that it makes me loose the page no list from my page whenever I click

Comment: But the question still remains that how to go inside that method ?? Anyone can help?

Comment: I will suggest you to create the controls(call the method CreatePagingControls) in page_init method

Comment: Updated answer with a working sample. Check if it works for you or else post your entire code.